# Generic implementation of 3rd party Libraries and Frameworks in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, libraries

I see there’s many libraries, open source, like Cocos2d, ShareKit, FormatterKit, etc. that seems up to date. (Check GitHub).

But still, implementation, snippets, samples and manual are intended to be written in Objective-C.

But, a method is a method… I think… If I get an instance of any framework/library of these and I call the method in a full Swift enviroment, would I be affected behind the scenes?

After June WWDC Swift gonna get serious, Apple is pushing hard, I’m just getting ready for the move and I don’t want my Apps to implement a soon-to-be deprecated library implementation in Objective-C.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Objective-C libraries aren't going to be deprecated.  Objective-C isn't going anywhere any time soon.  Despite this, since long before Swift, library methods, functions, classes, etc., have regularly been deprecated.

Comment: @nhgrift Hello nhgrift, glad to see your comment, yours are always welcome, you know how is Apple when pushing, Cook "urge to all developers" to move to Swift ASAP. When they recommend they mean it... But I don't want to get into this hot discussion topic, my core Q was, if I embed a 3rd party framework as say FormatterKit... And I code on Swift... would matter?

Comment: No.  You shouldn't be concerned.  It'd be good to be writing all your new code in Swift probably.... but if Apple has any intention of deprecating the massive chunks of libraries written in Objective-C, then we should all just start learning Android development.

Comment: LOL Good point! Yeah I meant mostly 3rd party libraries, I actually don't know how rigid is their implementation behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

- I do not understand your question so much that I will regard your question as "Is it possible to use the `Objective-C`&`Swift`in the same project?"

  Yes, Apple claimed that developers can use `Bridging-Header` to implement double languages development, whatever your main developing language is `ObjC` or `Swift`. The specific details and theories about it you shall check from [there](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_78).
- Next I want to tell you some errors occurred in my project when I used `Bridging-Header`.

  I always meet this kind of problem like `import 'file not found'`. I think you can try to check your `file&folder hierarchy`. Such as you have a root folder named Project, as is often the case, there is another Project in your previous Project, the root folder.

  And Checking the `Objective-C Bridging Header` in the Build Setting. Sometime error can occurred for `Project/Project/Bridging-Header.h`. And the error can be corrected by changing the definition as `Project/Bridging-Header.h`.

  If the location of `Bridging-Header.h` is not matching with the definition in the Build Setting, the error like `import file not found` will occur.
- I just tell your my solution for Bridging issue I already met, I hope it can help you.

Comment: My core Q was, if I embed a 3rd party framework as say FormatterKit... And I code on Swift... would matter?

Comment: Well, the matter for what? Your project with 3rd party framework can build&Run successfully and pass the Apple's verification to App Store.

Comment: Thank you Ethan for your comment, but please don't be hawkish with me, it makes me feel blue, I'm just trying to wonder what's coming, I'm not worry about the Apple revision, just the performance of an API writing (implement) in Objective-C Vs Swift.

Comment: I am sorry for making you feel blue, and I did not `hawkish` with you ! For the last comment, I just tried to ask why you worry about the 3rd framework. And English is not my native language, which means maybe my expression is not proper sometime.

Comment: Glad to read this Ethan, yes... Every time I talk about the Swift-Obj-C replacement people get angry with me... Please blame Apple, not me. I did nothing...

Comment: Yes ! People in there always get angry when I asked some questions which are regarded by them as simple easy things.